Does using Azure Whois api needs microsoft sentinel to be set up or it can be used stand alone
I just need whois information of domains and came across azure whois api. Do I need to set up azure sentinel or can I use api directly?. I have multiple virtual machines on azure. If I need to set up sentinel what will it cost since we won't be feeding it any logs .

You do not need to set up Microsoft Sentinel to use the Azure Whois API. The Azure Whois API can be used standalone to retrieve whois information for domains. However, if you want to use Microsoft Sentinel, it provides additional security features such as intelligent security analytics and threat intelligence across the enterprise. If you decide to use Microsoft Sentinel, the pricing and billing for it is based on the volume of data analyzed and stored in the Log Analytics workspace.

You can review the Microsoft Sentinel pricing to understand the cost impact and use the Azure pricing calculator to help estimate your costs.

@NaveenSharma whois api is asking for authentication token. I  requeries am app with insight.whois permsission. Any idea how to do it?

Initially, register one Entra ID application and create one client secret in it like this:

Now, I assigned Reader role to above service principal under Azure subscription:

To generate access token, I used client credentials flow with below parameters via Postman:
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id:appID
client_secret:secret
scope: https://management.azure.com/.default

Response:

When I used this token to call Domain Whois API, I got the response successfully as below:
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.SecurityInsights/enrichment/domain/whois/?api-version=2024-01-01-preview&domain={domain}

Response:

